# "Не" или "ни" в предложении "Деньги не возвращаются НЕ/НИ при каких обстоятельствах"?

Tags: орфография, морфология, словосочетания, не-или-ни

Возник спор по поводу написания "не/ни" в предложении:

> Деньги не возвращаются **НЕ** при каких обстоятельствах.

Как писать "не при каких" в данном контексте? Насколько я знаю, в данном случае идет двойное отрицание, но мой собеседник утверждает, что должно писаться "ни". Кто же прав?

Comment: Согласен с Екатериной. Если частицу можно опустить, ставится Ни.

Answer (score 4):

Нужно писать НИ.

***Деньги не возвращаются ни при каких обстоятельствах.*** НИ здесь всего лишь усиливает отрицание, выраженное глаголом с НЕ.

Ср.: *Деньги не возвращаются при любых обстоятельствах.*

Как видите, смысл предложения не меняется, хотя НИ убрали. При двойном отрицании удаление второго НЕ невозможно без ущерба для смысла предложения.

Answer (score -1):

1.1. Здесь стоит разбираться не с частицей "ни", а с приставкой, поскольку в именительном падеже это приставка, которая в других падежам из-за предлогов отделилась.

1.1.1. Удивителен факт того, что в наречиях "на ходу", "с разбегу", "дО смерти" (не путать с предл.+сущ. "до смЕрти"), "на днях" и т. д. "на-", "с-", "до-", "на-" соответстсвенно — это приставки, а не предлоги, которые почему-то пишутся раздельно, в отличие от "насмерть", "начистоту"…, где "на-" — приставка.

1.2. В отрицательных местоимениях и местоименных наречиях с "ни-" ударение не падает на "ни", в отличие от "не", на которую падает ударение:

> НигдЕ, нЕгде.

Так что правильно через И писать.

Comment: Не понятна аргументация, и нумерация тоже.